# When in container CLI, how to use Sublime text?

Tags: docker

When I access the CLI of a docker container, I then land in the docker container (so a virtual environment), but I don't have any text editor (not even nano or vim). So is it possible to install Sublimetext in the container CLI ?

Thanks a lot

Aymeric

Comment: You can install nano or vim depending on your container's distribution: `sudo apt-get install nano`. To access a GUI tool like Sublime Text, you'll have to attach a display to the Docker container if you're not bind-mounting directories from you host machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Day

It would be better if you mentioned what Linux distribution you are using in *Dockerfile*. As **tentative**. mentioned in comment we usually use *Vim* or *Nano* as a text editor in container..

But let's install *Sublime* anyway. I assumed you are using a [Debian based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Debian-based_distributions) Linux distribution.

Let's start with updating apt-get :

```
apt-get update
```

Then install sublime (no *sudo* needed)

```
wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | apt-key add -
```

You may get this error

> gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation

Let's install them too and try again:

```
apt-get install wget | apt-get install gnupg | wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | apt-key add -
```

Then

```
echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
```

And finally install Sublime itself:

```
apt install sublime-text
```

Check your Sublime using this:

```
subl --help
```

> Sublime Text build 3211

You can install *Vim* or *Nano* too just in similar way.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, my Linux distr is Linux version 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 (oe-user@oe-host) (gcc version 8.2.0 (GCC)) #1 SMP Wed Oct 28 23:40:43 UTC 2020   actually the last line of your solution have me a "E: Unable to locate package sublime-text"

Comment: @poutinsqqq did you update apt? As I recommend, use Vim or Nano to edit/create files inside containers.
use `apt-get update` and then `apt-get install vim` and finally edit/create files like `vi file.ext`